# How to use oracle datetime instead of client datetime with Linq?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I want to execute the script as below with Linq.

```
//Oracle script
UPDATE Table1 SET UPDATETIME = SYSDATE WHERE USERID = '1';

//Linq
var updateTbl = DbContext.Table1.Where(x=>x.USERID == "1").FirstOrDefalt();
updateTbl.UPDATETIME = DateTime.Now;
DbContext.SaveChange();
```

But after I retrieve the sql script, I found that Linq didn't use sysdate.

```
update "Table1"
set "UPDATETIME" = :p0
where ("USERID" = :p1)
-- :p0: '2021/3/4 09:55:07' (Type = DateTime) //DateTime on client instead of Oracle sysdate.
-- :p1: '1' (Type = String, Size = 128)
```

Some client will have wrong datetime, so I want to save datetime with oracle datetime instead of client datetime.

How to do it with Linq?
I want to execute the script like below.

```
update "Table1"
set "UPDATETIME" = :p0
where ("USERID" = :p1)
-- :p0: sysdate (Type = DateTime)
-- :p1: '1' (Type = String, Size = 128)
```

Comment: I've never used Oracle, and you also didn't explicitly say it, but I'm assuming this is in Entity Framework (especially since you mention DbContext), so are you using the right EF Provider? That usually addresses the conversion from LINQ to whatever underlying DB commands are used. I could be totally offbase, but just my un-googled thoughts.

Comment: yes, I want to insert sysdate with entity framework.

Answer (score -1):

Entity framework doesn't update rows in sets. First, you retrieve the objects (your FirstOrDeault materialize the object), then you modify the objects in memory, and last EF generate update sentences for each modified object (in SaveChanges method).

Since the updateTbl.UPDATETIME = DateTime.Now is executed in memory, it does not execute SQL code. The update code is generated way after the value has changed.

If you need to execute SQL without retrieving the object, you could use DbContext.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand. This let you create arbitrary or parametrized SQL, but, if you are modifying other fields, it may be hard to maintain.

I assume running app server and database server are not synchronized, and want to use the DB server time. Could you force the servers to synchronize?

Other option could be using a trigger in the table that updates the column each time the row is inserted / updated.